# Bootstrap form input: prevent submit, but allow for input checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I've got the following problem: 
I use bootstrap form to take input from users, and I use jQuery preventDefault() to disable the submit button from sending the form (I use AJAX instead). However, that function also prevents input checking that is done by bootstrap. For example, if someone enters an e-mail without '@' into

```
<input type="email" class="form-control">
```

bootstrap would, upon clicking submit, check that input and return a popup with an error.

My question is: how to prevent the request being sent while keeping the bootstrap form checking mechanism intact?

What I have tried: using preventDefault() and writing my own checking script, however this seems like reinventing the wheel and having extra code when it's not needed.

Thank you!

Comment: You are correct, it would be re-inventing the wheel a bit. I would recommend taking a look at http://bootstrapvalidator.com/ to help do the validation. It seems to handle it quite nicely...

Comment: Thanks! Bootstrap, by itself however, already has a mechanism for some "basic" input validation. So if I add a jQuery plugin, I won't reinvent the wheel, but I would add extra code that, perhaps, wasn't necessary. What I'm hoping to find out is if its possible to prevent the submit action only partially: allow for input checking but prevent a POST request being sent to submit the form.

Comment: Fair enough. If you were to use that however, you wouldn't really need to have to override the submit button anymore. Now i'm just getting away from the topic.

Comment: With some browsing around, it seems the only way to really get what you are after is to have a .submit method on your form, then do your validation, then submit (I can provide a code sample if you like). In terms of bootstrap doing it for you, that's handled through something like http://bootstrapvalidator.com/, or http://jqueryvalidation.org/... If there is something different, I'm yet to hear of it...

Comment: I think that a Fiddle of your code would be ideal to help you out with this fast.

Answer (score 19):

I believe you are talking about the native HTML5 form validation and not validation by bootstrap its self, I have never come across bootstrap validation before. (i may be wrong though).

Most new browsers will validate `<input type='email'/>` as an email address and `<input type='text' required='required'/>` as required on form submission.

If for example you are using `e.preventDefault();` on the click event on the submit button the form will never attempt to submit and hence the native validation will never happen.

If you want to keep the validation you need to use `e.preventDefault();` on the submit event of the form not the click event on the button.

The html...

```
<form action='' method='post'>
   <input type='email' name='email' required='required' placeholder='email'/>
   <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

The jQuery...

```
//this will stop the click on the button and will not trigger validation as the submit event will never be triggered
$("button").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //ajax code here
});

//this will stop the submit of the form but allow the native HTML5 validation (which is what i believe you are after)
$("form").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //ajax code here
});
```

Anyway hope this helps. If I have misunderstood in any way let me know and ill try to assist further.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new today. Why is this not an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I came to use "stopPropagation" as the way to stop the form submission. But after a little reading on jQuery 3, I realized that "preventDefault" was enough to what I wanted.

**This caused the form validation to happen and the submit event didn't proceed.**

(This example is of an attempt i had on my own).

```
$('form').on("submit",function( event ) {

if ( $('#id_inputBox_username').val().length == 0 && 
$('#id_inputBox_password').val().length == 0 ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#id_inputBox_username').tooltip('show');
    $('#id_inputBox_password').tooltip('show');         

} else if ( $('#id_inputBox_username').val().length == 0 ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#id_inputBox_username').tooltip('show');

} else if ( $('#id_inputBox_password').val().length == 0 ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#id_inputBox_password').tooltip('show'); 
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I find this solution:

```
$('#formulario').on('submit', function (e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
  } else {
    // everything looks good!
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent submit
            $(".imprimir").show();
            $(".informacao").fadeOut();
            carregardados();
  }
})
```

Comment: You should provide information about where you found that solution.

Comment: Your answer is about bootstrap-validation. It has nothing to do with this question.